# when i am hitting the celery beat cmd it running continuesly

Tags: django-celery

[2023-10-11 14:20:44,900: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2023-10-11 14:20:45,704: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task check_website_status_1_min3 (monitoring.tasks.check_website_status)
[2023-10-11 14:20:46,002: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task check_website_status_1_min3 (monitoring.tasks.check_website_status)
[2023-10-11 14:20:46,136: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task check_website_status_1_min3 (monitoring.tasks.check_website_status)
[2023-10-11 14:20:46,261: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task check_website_status_1_min3 (monitoring.tasks.check_website_status)
[2023-10-11 14:20:46,371: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task check_website_status_1_min3 (monitoring.tasks.check_website_status)
[2023-10-11 14:20:46,503: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task check_website_status_1_min3 (monitoring.tasks.check_website_status)

I need proper explanation to fix it